# Can list_filter be done on the count of foreign key objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hi I have two objects:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

In the admin I would like to filter A objects that have more than 2 Bs associated to them. Is that possible?

I tried adding 'b_set__count' to list filter but I'm getting this error

```
The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'b_set__count', which does not refer to a Field.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. What you need to do is modify `get_queryset` to return a qs that annotates the related count:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, *args,  **kwargs):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset (*args, **kwargs)
        return qs.annotate(b_count=Count('b_set'))
```

Now you can use `b_count` in ordering, list_display, list_filter etc.

Comment: Hi I'm doing

`return super(..., self).get_queryset (*args, **kwargs).annotate(payment_count=Count('payment_set'))`


and I'm still getting 

`The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to payment_count', which does not refer to a Field`

Comment: Hi , first thanks for the answer! then, I tried this and I could use it in list_display if I also add a method that gets this value. Its useful because I can add admin_order_field and it is just like a field. However, I still can't get it on list_filter. Any clues?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, actually this doesn't work with `list_filter`, is it a bug?

Comment: hit on it today I guess you need a custom filter